# Mapear controles windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação descktop em c#
O framework 4.5

Não imaginava que a aplicação poderia crescer e ter muitos campos, com isso veio a necessidade de fazer um mapeamento automático (de / para) dos controles para entidades...

Exemplo.

```
public Pessoa GetPessoaForm()
{
    //Obtém todos os controles de um formulário
    IEnumerable<Control> controles = frm.GetAll();

    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

    var prop = typeof(pessoa).GetProperties();

    foreach ( Controle control in controles)
    {  
        foreach (var p in prop)
        { 
            If(!p.Name.ToLower().Equals(control.Tag.ToString().ToLower())
                continue;

            If (typeof(control).Equals(typeof(TextBox))
                Control.Text = p.GetValue(prop, null); //erro também
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa forma gostaria de fazer o mapeamento para o formulário e vice versa.
Do formulário para entidades.

Comment: Qual é o erro que lhe dá quando tenta atribuir o valor?

Comment: Objeto nullo, talvez esteja tentando resgatar a propriedade de forma errada, existe algum framework pra fazer esse tipo de mapeamento automático?

Comment: Dê uma procurada em frameworks MVVM ou MVP para WinForms. Não sei se tem algo bom disponível...

Comment: O problema deve ser o momento e o lugar em que esse método é chamado. Geralmente os controles são criados apenas quando o formulário é inicializado. Além disso, se o formulário conter painéis ou outros tipos de _'containers'_, você terá que criar uma recursão nesse laço que itera os controles do formulário a fim de checar todos os seus controles-filhos.

Comment: @Linq boa sujestão, se exige no mundo web, talvez haja no mundo desk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque a classe `Pessoa` a notificar alterações de propriedade (através do *interface* `INotifyPropertyChanged`), da seguinte forma:

```
class Pessoa : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string nome;
    public string Nome
    {
        get { return nome; }
        set
        {
            nome = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Nome"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

E depois pode utilizar o `Binding` direto:

```
foreach (Controle control in controles)
{  
    foreach (var p in prop)
    { 
        if(!p.Name.ToLower().Equals(control.Tag.ToString().ToLower())
            continue;

        if (typeof(control).Equals(typeof(TextBox))
            // supondo que a classe Pessoa tem uma propriedade "Nome"
            Control.DataBindings.Add("Text", pessoa, "Nome");
    }
}
```

Desta forma o valor da propriedade `Nome` da classe `Pessoa` estará diretamente ligado ao texto da `TextBox`.

Comment: Me parece uma ótima opção, vejo qualquer dá pra deixar ainda a aos dinamico o código. Irei verificar.